# ON DELETE CASCADE not being set in DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Im trying to create to domain objects with a OneToOne relationship. A is the parent and B is the child.

I tried many different ways to cascade deletions from A to B but when i look a the database creation, it doesnt set up ON DELETE CASCADE.

Can someone see what im doing wrong

A:

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "financeaccountcurrencymapping")
    public class FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "financeAccountCurrencyMapping")
        private FinanceAccount financeAccount;
```

I know that either CascadeType.ALL or orphanRemoval should do the trick, but they dont.

B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "financeaccount")
public class FinanceAccount implements Serializable {


    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    private FinanceAccountCurrencyMapping financeAccountCurrencyMapping;
```

Can someone see why it doesnt cascade deletions?

Comment: I would prefer JPA implementations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but not with JPA

i set @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) on the child